# WPF doubleanimation : animate in steps?

Tags: wpf, animation

In my current application I have this little animation. It makes a full 360 degrees rotation of a canvas and works fine.

```
<DoubleAnimation
 Storyboard.TargetName="WaitCanvas" 
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0]  
 .(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
 From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:2"
 AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
```

But the thing I want to do is not a smooth animation but animation is steps of 22.5 degrees each. How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [`DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimationusingkeyframes.aspx) and make two keyframes for each increment of 22.5 degrees at the same point in time.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the XAML example which I was actually searching for.

```
<Storyboard
    BeginTime="00:00:00"
    RepeatBehavior="Forever"
    Storyboard.TargetName="WaitCanvas" 
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:2">
        <DoubleKeyFrameCollection>
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.000" Value="0" />
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.125" Value="22.5" />
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.250" Value="45" />
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.375" Value="67.5" />
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.500" Value="90" />
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.625" Value="110.5" />
            <!-- ... -->
        </DoubleKeyFrameCollection>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score -3):

Even easier, use the DoubleAnimation "By" property, as in:

```
<DoubleAnimation 
 Storyboard.TargetName="WaitCanvas"  
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0]   
 .(RotateTransform.Angle)"  
 From="0" To="360" By="22.5" Duration="0:0:2"
 AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
```

Comment: `DoubleAnimation.By` does not do what you claim. From MSDN, the definition of the `By` property is 'Gets or sets the total amount by which the animation changes its starting value.' It continues, 'Use the By property when you want to animate a value "by" a certain amount, rather than specifying a starting or ending value.'